# Firebase dynamic links Android fallbackURL is not working

Tags: ios, firebase, dynamic, firebase-dynamic-links

At the moment we only have the iOS application and we are using Firebase dynamic links.
A dynamic link is created programmatically using a link builder.

```
    var urlComponents = URLComponents()
    urlComponents.scheme = "https"
    urlComponents.host = "our host"
    urlComponents.path = "/link_path"
    
    guard let linkParameter = urlComponents.url else {
        return completion(nil)
    }
            
    let dynamicLinksDomainURIPrefix = "our domain"
    let linkBuilder = DynamicLinkComponents(
         link: linkParameter, domainURIPrefix: dynamicLinksDomainURIPrefix
    )
    if let myBundleId = Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier {
    linkBuilder?.iOSParameters = DynamicLinkIOSParameters(bundleID: myBundleId)
    }
    linkBuilder?.iOSParameters?.appStoreID = "our app store id"
    
    let androidParameters = DynamicLinkAndroidParameters(packageName: "package name")
    androidParameters.fallbackURL = URL(string: "our fallback URL")
    androidParameters.minimumVersion = 1
    linkBuilder?.androidParameters = androidParameters
            
    linkBuilder?.otherPlatformParameters = DynamicLinkOtherPlatformParameters()
    linkBuilder?.otherPlatformParameters?.fallbackUrl = URL(string: "our fallback URL")
    
    linkBuilder?.socialMetaTagParameters = DynamicLinkSocialMetaTagParameters()
    linkBuilder?.socialMetaTagParameters?.title = "title"
    linkBuilder?.socialMetaTagParameters?.descriptionText = "description"
    linkBuilder?.socialMetaTagParameters?.imageURL = URL(string: "image url")
    
    linkBuilder?.shorten(completion: { url, warnings, error in
        completion(url)
     })
```

This code works for iOS (it opens AppStore if the app is not installed and it opens the app if it is installed).
It also works for desktops. If opened on a desktop it goes to the `fallbackURL`.

It is just not working on Android. On Android, it is opening a blank page instead of a fallbackURL no matter what I tried.
Since we don't have the Android app, I have also tried to ommit android parameters, but the result is the same - blank page.

Am I missing something? What do I need to add/remove for Android to open a fallback URL?

The fallback URL is in format: http://www.ourdomain.com

Answer (score 1):

I have found a way to achieve this. Please follow the below steps.

Add a dummy Android app in your firebase console. Please use a dummy app nickname and dummy package name for the Android app.

Then, please add the below code:

```
linkBuilder.androidParameters = DynamicLinkAndroidParameters(packageName: "dummy.androidapp.package.name ")
linkBuilder.androidParameters?.minimumVersion = 1
linkBuilder.androidParameters?.fallbackURL = URL(string:"https://stackoverflow.com")
```

The newly generated links will work in Android.

Comment: Thanks, man! You saved me! I hope nobody will create this bundle package. 